# RAM memory optimization at compilation

Tags: c, ram

I am working on a project it is in C programing language, I'm trying to analyze  the RAM memory (segment allocations )  at  compilation time for library files on specific feature. That will help me out statically to optimize my data size at compilation level itself.

I am using Wind River(Diab 5.8) compiler. That can be run on Freescale microcontroller platforms. I am developing this application on Windows environment. Please help me to find this.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `-m` to the linker that should be sufficient to get it to print out a list of segment allocations. That way you'll be able to see how much of your code segment is taken up by a particular (statically linked) library.

Comment: Are you sure? At least for Diab 5.6, the option for getting a map dump is `-m`. `-M` results in "Invalid option format: -M".

Comment: It's -m then, for most linkers it's -M (and GNU LD has the nice --print-map), but I've never worked with Diab. Still the link map should show you what you need.

Comment: I just checked to manual for Diab 5.8 and indeed it is `-m`, so I fixed your answer (and upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, understood the difference of architecture: Have you tried [this?](http://cache.freescale.com/files/soft_dev_tools/doc/app_note/AN4329.pdf)

Comment: I suspect that on this microcontroller, which of course needn't have an OS, the compiler (well, linker) *does* assign particular RAM ranges to particular purposes. So for example the rwdata segment will be at some chosen address that gets fixed up by the static linker.